# Xbox Live API for Windows Phone

Tags: xbox-live

If my game targets both Windows, Xbox, and Windows Phone - is the API supported on Windows Phone? or should I do a check and if it's Phone not use the APIs?

Comment: It's the XBox API. The name makes it clear that it's for the XBox, doesn't it?

Comment: Ken, this question was actually asking of the Xbox Live API.  Many of the Xbox Live services are accessible from a wide variety of devices from Windows PCs to iOS phones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Xbox Live API with any Windows 10 UWP project which includes Windows 10 Phone. There are no restrictions other than your internet access to connect to the service.

If your game is based on C++ just incorporate the NuGet package like described here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/get-started/creators/getting-started-uwp-vs-creators

If your game is based on C# it is a little bit more complicated as you have to include the existing API source files by yourself. You will find the source code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api-csharp

Comment: You don't necessarily need to include the C# source files directly, the github repo should allow you to build the library yourself and then just include that reference.  We will be creating a NuGet package eventually, it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Ben Randall That repo seems to have disappeared. I would love to be able to debug my Xbox Live UWP errors are I'm unable to get Leaderabords works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no longer with the company.  You'd have to get in touch with developer support to see if there's a replacement API available.